# Is possible to convert linq lambda expressions to SQL using dart?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, dart

I know that it is possible to create linq like expressions in dart as shows this link:

https://github.com/dartist/101LinqSamples

However, I would like to know if it is possible to achieve the same approach that we can get with C# and Java8, ie. convert lambda expressions to SQL like in this link:

https://code.google.com/p/lambda-sql-builder/

Comment: I think it would be possible to create a transformer that processes the code and generates SQL from it. But I would not expect this to be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible for the built-in methods (where, etc.); and I'm not really sure you could build it yourself without significant effort (and a transformer).

In C#, the `Where` method used in EF is not the same `Where` method that you see on `IEnumerable<T>`, but rather an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`. The method signatures are different:

```
// IEnumerable<T>
Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,            Func<T, Boolean>  predicate)
// IQueryable<T>
Where<T>(this  IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)
```

The use of `Expression` is important; it means the method gets additional information about the lambda that was passed, and can walk down the expressions building up SQL from the (supported) operators inside it.

I'm not aware of anything in Dart that would allow similar decomposition of an expression. Mirrors will let you inspect types, but I don't think they can inspect arbitrary Dart expressions.

Transformers, however, probably can help. It shouldn't be hard to get the AST of a document and walk down it looking for calls to `where()` on your special "database types", and then rewrite them. I suspect doing this will involve many more StackOverflow questions!